# How to run node application in cpanel and is that required to setup .htaccess file

Tags: node.js, cpanel

i want to run the node application in cPanel server how to configure and run node application in cPanel server.

Answer (score 3):

You should add the following code in the .htaccessfile 
where XXXXX is the port number

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXXX/ [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXXX/$1 [P,L]
```

Then you should type in your terminal

```
    nohup npm start &
```

and in your package.json don't forget to add this script

```
    "start": "nodemon index.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2"
```